# Problem with loading custom widget

Tags: qt

I have developed a custom widget for qt. Not able to load it in my designer. 
I have done make install. I have checked, the widget is present in /usr/lib/plugins/designer folder. What is going wrong. Why the widget is not displaying ?

Regards

Comment: Have you followed all the steps mentioned in this tutorial : http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/designer-customwidgetplugin.html